# Why is $t^2+1$ not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[t]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it because $t+1=t-1$ in this ring, and so $t^2+1=(t+1)(t+1)$?

Comment: Yep, that's right, since also $t+1$ is not a unit.

Comment: ... and nonzero, i.e. irreducibles are nonzero and nonunit by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of seeing that $t^2+1$ is reducible. A polynomial with coefficients in a field $F$  of degree 2 (or 3) being reducible  is equivalent to having a root in $F$.(Then for such a root $a$ one can factorize with $(t-a)$ as a factor).

Here $t=1$ makes the value of polynomial zero thereby showing reducibility.

Now in any field of prime characteristic $p$ one has $(a+b)^p = a^p + b^p$.

Using this we can see $(t+1)^2= t^2+1^2= t^2+1$ thus showing this polynomial is reducible.(has repeated roots).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in that ring $ 1 = -1 $ (their difference is in $2 \mathbb Z[t]$) so $t+1=t-1$ and so $t^2+1=t^2-1=(t+1)(t-1)=(t+1)(t+1)$

Answer (score 0):

It has a root:  $1^2+1=2\cong0\pmod2$.